# Accessing camera of windows 8 tablet

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, wpf-mediakit

I'm trying to write code to access the camera function of a Windows 8 tablet in a WPF application.

The threads I've found all seem to point to using [DirectShow.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/) or [MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/). Neither of these projects have been updated in over 3 years. Is still the best way to go or are there any other ideas on how to do it?

Comment: [WPF-MediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit) has moved and is maintained again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question here.

From what I've found, in Windows 8, you should be using the Windows.Media namespace's MediaCapture class to do it. DirectShow and MediaKit are for legacy systems.

I am in the middle of getting this to work, but in case anyone needs help, here's the best sample I've found so far:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm searching on examples how to do it.

Comment: If you got it working, can you update your answer and add the solution too?